# Solving a problem with L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus

$$\lim _{x \to 2 \pi} (\cos x) ^{1/\sin ^22x} $$
I know that I should get it into $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ form. How should I do it?

Comment: start by taking logarithm and finding its limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* $$\ln \left((\cos x)^{1/\sin^2 2x}\right) = \dfrac{\ln \cos x}{\sin^2 2x}.$$

Comment: $$\ln \left((\cos x) ^{1/\sin ^22x}\right) = \dfrac{\ln \cos x}{\sin ^22x}$$ first derivative:
$$\frac{-\tan x}{2\sin 4x} $$
second:
$$\frac{-\frac1{\cos ^2 x}}{8\cos 4x} = e^{-\frac18} $$ is that correct?

Comment: Your answer is correct. But your last equality is not correct.

Comment: It should have been like this: $$\lim _{x \to 2 \pi} (\cos x) ^{1/\sin ^22x}=e^{-\frac18}$$  Last equality would be $-\frac18 $ then.